# How to programmatically combine multiple graphql queries

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, gql

I am trying to set up a search page with multiple inputs users can filter/order by. Is there a standard way to programmatically combine the user's selections? For example, I have one query that can query for items with a `timestamp` property greater than a variable argument, and I have another query that fetches all items and sorts them by another field. In the UI, users have the ability to turn these filters on or off, or select different options to filter by. Right now I am combining them by using string interpolation, to make a big string based on various react state values, and also making a variables object based on the same state values, but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this, as it is quickly becoming a bit of a mess.

For clarification, on its own, one query looks like this:

```
export const ITEMS_WITH_TIMESTAMP_GT = gql`
    query getItemsWithTimestampGreaterThan($x: Int!) {
        items(where: { timestamp_gt: $x }) {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

and another which, on its own, looks like this:

```
export const ITEMS_BY_AMOUNT = gql`
    query getItemsByAmount {
        items(orderBy: amount, orderDirection: desc) {
            id
        }
    }
`;
```

Currently my attempt to combine them together looks like this (selectByTimestamp and orderByAmount are react state values, booleans turned on or off in the ui)

```
const queryString = gql`
    combinedQuery${selectByTimestamp ? "($timestamp: Int!)" : ""} {
        items(${selectByTimestamp ? "where: {timestamp_gt: $timestamp}" : ""}${orderByAmount ? ", orderBy: amount" : ""}) {
            id
        }
    }
`
```

With just these two queries its already getting pretty messy. There are also other search filters, and since users can select to use them or not use them, I can't just merge them into one big hardcoded query. Will I need to make a query string for every possible combination of them?

Comment: you can pass a variable which will pass an object. Lets say your variable name is `$object`. Now inside this object you can pass parameters like `filters`, `sortby` etc. If any field is not selected pass a null and handle it from your backend.

Comment: I don't have control of the backend because it is a subgraph generated by thegraph